# How can I update Box2d?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d, box2d-iphone

I updated cocos2d template but it doesn't have the new box2d.

```
http://code.google.com/p/box2d/downloads/detail?name=Box2D_v2.2.1.zip&can=2&q=
```

How can i update my box2d alone?
When i try to switch box2d folders, i get errors.

Answer (score 0):

Box2D 2.1.1 came out in September 2011. Cocos2D 2.x definitely includes this version of Box2D, v1.1 ought to but I haven't checked. Verify that you've installed the cocos2d templates correctly, from a recent version of cocos2d.

Comment: I have cocos2D 1.x. It does not have the newest Box2D